# MS Excel SQL query with grouped and not grouped sum

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am working with a VBA macro and trying to perform a query over a table that is in an excel sheet. My query starts with a simple select distinct over all the text fields and the boolean fields. I need every possible combination between them, and the sum of their amounts. My table (abbreviated) looks like

```
Txt1    Txt2    Txt3    Amt1    Amt2    Bool1   Bool2   Bool3
A       B          F    10      1000    YES     YES     YES
A       D          F    20       200    YES     YES     YES
A       B          F    5        100    YES     YES     YES
A       B          G    10      1200    NO      YES     NO
A       D          H    5       1300    NO      YES     NO
A       B          I    30       500    YES     YES     NO
A       B          J    10       600    YES     YES     YES
A       D          K    6        800    YES     YES     YES
A       B          F    4       1000    NO      YES     YES
A       B          F    2       2900    NO      YES     NO
A       D          F    6       3150    YES     YES     NO
A       B          F    1       3400    YES     YES     NO
A       B          F    0       3650    YES     YES     YES
A       D          F    5       3900    NO      YES     YES
A       B          H    15      4150    NO      YES     YES
A       B          F    2       4400    YES     YES     NO
A       D          F    1       4650    YES     YES     NO
A       B          F    5       4900    YES     YES     NO
A       B          G    6       5150    NO      NO      YES
A       D          H    8       5400    NO      NO      YES
A       B          I    2        100    YES     YES     YES
```

This is where I got with this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW [Txt1], [Txt2], [Txt3], [Bool1], [Bool2], [Bool3], Sum([Amt1]) AS [Sum Amt1], Sum([Amt2]) AS [Sum Amt2] 
FROM [mytable] 
GROUP BY [Txt1], [Txt2], [Txt3], [Bool1], [Bool2], [Bool3];
```

And it works:

```
Txt1   Txt2   Txt3   Bool1   Bool2   Bool3   Sum Amt1   Sum Amt2
    A     B     F     NO     YES     NO       2               2900
    A     B     F     NO     YES     YES      4               1000
    A     B     F     YES    YES     NO       8               12700
    A     B     F     YES    YES     YES      15              4750
    A     B     G     NO     NO      YES      6               5150
    A     B     G     NO     YES     NO       10              1200
    A     B     H     NO     YES     YES      15              4150
    A     B     I     YES    YES     NO       30              500
    A     B     I     YES    YES     YES      2               100
    A     B     J     YES    YES     YES      10              600
    A     D     F     NO     YES     YES      5               3900
    A     D     F     YES    YES     NO       7               7800
    A     D     F     YES    YES     YES      20              200
    A     D     H     NO     NO      YES      8               5400
    A     D     H     NO     YES     NO       5               1300
    A     D     K     YES    YES     YES      6               800
```

*BUT* what I really need is the same with a field/column which sums each combination between the Text fields or even better a summary row that includes the Bool fields.  If I do:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW [Txt1], [Txt2], [Txt3], Sum([Amt1]) AS [Sum Amt1], Sum([Amt2]) AS [Sum Amt2] 
FROM [mytable] 
GROUP BY [Txt1], [Txt2], [Txt3];
```

I get rid of the Bool fields and get the summary, but the case is I don't know how to get both querys together.

```
Txt1   Txt2 Txt3    Sum Amt1    Sum Amt2
A       B      F       29      21350
A       B      G       16       6350
A       B      H       15       4150
A       B      I       32        600
A       B      J       10        600
A       D      F       32      11900
A       D      H       13       6700
A       D      K        6        800
```

I tried adding a dummy boolean column to my table, and add the dummy field to my query (both to the select and to the group instructions), but it simply yielded an error message (-2147217904, missing parameters).

I suspect that I need some kind of JOIN, but that goes clearly beyond my knowledge of SQL. Any help, please?

[edited]
Well something like this would be ok (See SumGrouped field):

```
Txt1   Txt2   Txt3   Bool1   Bool2   Bool3   Sum Amt1   Sum Amt2     SumGrouped
    A     B     F     NO     YES     NO       2               2900     21350
    A     B     F     NO     YES     YES      4               1000     21350
    A     B     F     YES    YES     NO       8               12700    21350
    A     B     F     YES    YES     YES      15              4750     21350
    A     B     G     NO     NO      YES      6               5150     6350
    A     B     G     NO     YES     NO       10              1200     6350
    A     B     H     NO     YES     YES      15              4150     4150
    A     B     I     YES    YES     NO       30              500      600
    A     B     I     YES    YES     YES      2               100      600
    A     B     J     YES    YES     YES      10              600      600
    A     D     F     NO     YES     YES      5               3900     11900
    A     D     F     YES    YES     NO       7               7800     11900
    A     D     F     YES    YES     YES      20              200      11900
    A     D     H     NO     NO      YES      8               5400     6700
    A     D     H     NO     YES     NO       5               1300     6700
    A     D     K     YES    YES     YES      6               800      800
```

And yes, now I wonder if it's easier using Pivot Table

Comment: Add your expected output for better answer

Comment: Isn't this simply solved by using a pivottable?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by `the same with a field/column which sums each combination between the Text fields`.  You would benefit from showing an example.  Using a PIVOT TABLE might do what you want, or possibly `GROUP BY x, y, z WITH ROLLUP`, or maybe just using `UNION ALL`.  While your question is ambiguous you won't get a clear answer.

Comment: Not sure it this will work since I don't have much experience in running SQL-like queries in Excel, but maybe [that can help](https://pastebin.com/5B8mSguN). I did a join between the two queries you had.

Comment: The `DISTINCTROW` key word shouldn't be needed since you are using a `GROUP BY` query which already ensures that distinct values are returned for the columns in the group list, and the other columns will be aggregates/summaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply join the two queries in a main outer query. Specifically, use your two aggregate queries (where `DISTINCTROW` is redundant) as derived tables (i.e., subqueries in `FROM` or `JOIN` clauses) and then join them on text fields.

```sql
SELECT allagg.*, textagg.[Sum Amt2] AS SumGrouped
FROM
  (SELECT [Txt1], [Txt2], [Txt3], [Bool1], [Bool2], [Bool3],
          Sum([Amt1]) AS [Sum  Amt1], Sum([Amt2]) AS [Sum Amt2] 
   FROM [mytable] 
   GROUP BY [Txt1], [Txt2], [Txt3], [Bool1], [Bool2], [Bool3]) As allagg

INNER JOIN      
  (SELECT [Txt1], [Txt2], [Txt3],
          Sum([Amt1]) AS [Sum Amt1], Sum([Amt2])  AS [Sum Amt2] 
   FROM [mytable] 
   GROUP BY [Txt1], [Txt2], [Txt3]) As textagg

ON allagg.[Txt1] = textagg.[Txt1]
AND allagg.[Txt2] = textagg.[Txt2]
AND allagg.[Txt3] = textagg.[Txt3]
```

And you can add *boolagg* as a third derived table. And if running SQL inside MS Excel, you will be using the Jet/ACE SQL dialect which requires parentheses wrapping with more than 2 tables in `JOIN` clauses.

```sql
SELECT allagg.*, textagg.[Sum Amt2] AS SumTxtGrouped, boolagg.[Sum Amt2] AS SumBoolGrouped
FROM
  ((SELECT [Txt1], [Txt2], [Txt3], [Bool1], [Bool2], [Bool3],
          Sum([Amt1]) AS [Sum  Amt1], Sum([Amt2]) AS [Sum Amt2] 
   FROM [mytable] 
   GROUP BY [Txt1], [Txt2], [Txt3], [Bool1], [Bool2], [Bool3]) As allagg

INNER JOIN      
  (SELECT [Txt1], [Txt2], [Txt3],
          Sum([Amt1]) AS [Sum Amt1], Sum([Amt2])  AS [Sum Amt2] 
   FROM [mytable] 
   GROUP BY [Txt1], [Txt2], [Txt3]) As textgg

ON allagg.[Txt1] = textagg.[Txt1]
AND allagg.[Txt2] = textagg.[Txt2]
AND allagg.[Txt3] = textagg.[Txt3])

INNER JOIN      
  (SELECT [Bool1], [Bool2], [Bool3],
          Sum([Amt1]) AS [Sum Amt1], Sum([Amt2])  AS [Sum Amt2] 
   FROM [mytable] 
   GROUP BY [Bool1], [Bool2], [Bool3]) As boolagg

ON allagg.[Bool1] = boolagg.[Bool1]
AND allagg.[Bool2] = boolagg.[Bool2]
AND allagg.[Bool3] = boolagg.[Bool3]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers, Jerry and Parfait. I have to leave it now but I'll try them later.

Comment: Since Parfait's first option accomplishes what I asked for, I will keep it.  I could not reproduce the second option. There is some "Syntax error in FROM clause" that I could not find, but anyway thank you very much to everybody contributing.

Comment: Found my overlook. Remove the very last parenthesis!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `GROUP BY ROLLUP` to get your desired resutls.  The parentheses around the columns in the `GROUP BY ROLLUP` define the grouping sets you are interested in.  The lowest level of detail groups on all six columns, the next lowest level of detail groups on just the 3 txt columns.  the final least granular level summarizes all records.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/65245/17)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT [Txt1], [Txt2], [Txt3]
     , [Bool1], [Bool2], [Bool3]
     , Sum([Amt1]) AS [Sum Amt1], Sum([Amt2]) AS [Sum Amt2] 
  FROM [mytable] 
 GROUP BY ROLLUP ( ([Txt1], [Txt2], [Txt3])
                 , ([Bool1], [Bool2], [Bool3]))
 ORDER BY grouping_id([txt1],[bool1])
     , [Txt1], [Txt2], [Txt3]
     , [Bool1], [Bool2], [Bool3]
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/65245/17/0)**:

```
|   Txt1 |   Txt2 |   Txt3 |  Bool1 |  Bool2 |  Bool3 | Sum Amt1 | Sum Amt2 |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|----------|----------|
|      A |      B |      F |     NO |    YES |     NO |        2 |     2900 |
|      A |      B |      F |     NO |    YES |    YES |        4 |     1000 |
|      A |      B |      F |    YES |    YES |     NO |        8 |    12700 |
|      A |      B |      F |    YES |    YES |    YES |       15 |     4750 |
|      A |      B |      G |     NO |     NO |    YES |        6 |     5150 |
|      A |      B |      G |     NO |    YES |     NO |       10 |     1200 |
|      A |      B |      H |     NO |    YES |    YES |       15 |     4150 |
|      A |      B |      I |    YES |    YES |     NO |       30 |      500 |
|      A |      B |      I |    YES |    YES |    YES |        2 |      100 |
|      A |      B |      J |    YES |    YES |    YES |       10 |      600 |
|      A |      D |      F |     NO |    YES |    YES |        5 |     3900 |
|      A |      D |      F |    YES |    YES |     NO |        7 |     7800 |
|      A |      D |      F |    YES |    YES |    YES |       20 |      200 |
|      A |      D |      H |     NO |     NO |    YES |        8 |     5400 |
|      A |      D |      H |     NO |    YES |     NO |        5 |     1300 |
|      A |      D |      K |    YES |    YES |    YES |        6 |      800 |
|      A |      B |      F | (null) | (null) | (null) |       29 |    21350 |
|      A |      B |      G | (null) | (null) | (null) |       16 |     6350 |
|      A |      B |      H | (null) | (null) | (null) |       15 |     4150 |
|      A |      B |      I | (null) | (null) | (null) |       32 |      600 |
|      A |      B |      J | (null) | (null) | (null) |       10 |      600 |
|      A |      D |      F | (null) | (null) | (null) |       32 |    11900 |
|      A |      D |      H | (null) | (null) | (null) |       13 |     6700 |
|      A |      D |      K | (null) | (null) | (null) |        6 |      800 |
| (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |      153 |    52450 |
```

**Query 2** Simulated ROLLUP:

```
SELECT [Txt1], [Txt2], [Txt3]
     , [Bool1], [Bool2], [Bool3]
     , Sum([Amt1]) AS [Sum Amt1], Sum([Amt2]) AS [Sum Amt2] 
  FROM [mytable] 
 GROUP BY [Txt1], [Txt2], [Txt3]
        , [Bool1], [Bool2], [Bool3]
UNION ALL
SELECT [Txt1], [Txt2], [Txt3]
     , NULL, NULL, NULL
     , Sum([Amt1]) AS [Sum Amt1], Sum([Amt2]) AS [Sum Amt2] 
  FROM [mytable] 
 GROUP BY [Txt1], [Txt2], [Txt3]
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL
     , NULL, NULL, NULL
     , Sum([Amt1]) AS [Sum Amt1], Sum([Amt2]) AS [Sum Amt2] 
  FROM [mytable]
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/65245/17/1)**:

```
|   Txt1 |   Txt2 |   Txt3 |  Bool1 |  Bool2 |  Bool3 | Sum Amt1 | Sum Amt2 |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|--------|----------|----------|
|      A |      B |      F |     NO |    YES |     NO |        2 |     2900 |
|      A |      B |      F |     NO |    YES |    YES |        4 |     1000 |
|      A |      B |      F |    YES |    YES |     NO |        8 |    12700 |
|      A |      B |      F |    YES |    YES |    YES |       15 |     4750 |
|      A |      B |      G |     NO |     NO |    YES |        6 |     5150 |
|      A |      B |      G |     NO |    YES |     NO |       10 |     1200 |
|      A |      B |      H |     NO |    YES |    YES |       15 |     4150 |
|      A |      B |      I |    YES |    YES |     NO |       30 |      500 |
|      A |      B |      I |    YES |    YES |    YES |        2 |      100 |
|      A |      B |      J |    YES |    YES |    YES |       10 |      600 |
|      A |      D |      F |     NO |    YES |    YES |        5 |     3900 |
|      A |      D |      F |    YES |    YES |     NO |        7 |     7800 |
|      A |      D |      F |    YES |    YES |    YES |       20 |      200 |
|      A |      D |      H |     NO |     NO |    YES |        8 |     5400 |
|      A |      D |      H |     NO |    YES |     NO |        5 |     1300 |
|      A |      D |      K |    YES |    YES |    YES |        6 |      800 |
|      A |      B |      F | (null) | (null) | (null) |       29 |    21350 |
|      A |      B |      G | (null) | (null) | (null) |       16 |     6350 |
|      A |      B |      H | (null) | (null) | (null) |       15 |     4150 |
|      A |      B |      I | (null) | (null) | (null) |       32 |      600 |
|      A |      B |      J | (null) | (null) | (null) |       10 |      600 |
|      A |      D |      F | (null) | (null) | (null) |       32 |    11900 |
|      A |      D |      H | (null) | (null) | (null) |       13 |     6700 |
|      A |      D |      K | (null) | (null) | (null) |        6 |      800 |
| (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |      153 |    52450 |
```

Comment: Sentinel's answer seems **exactly** what I am looking for. Amazing work with fiddle too. ...unfortunately that `GROUP BY ROLLUP` didn't work for me. Maybe it doesn't exist in the excel 2007's VBA SQL I am programming into?

Comment: MS Excel and Windows programs uses the [Jet/ACE SQL Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Jet_Database_Engine) (which is MS Access' engine - Windows .dll files) distinct from the SQL Server dialect that uses `ROLLUP`.

Comment: If the backend DB doesn't support `ROLLUP` or `CUBE` functionality, you will need to simulate it with `UNION ALL` queries. See the second query (just added) above.

Comment: Nice work-round, Sentinel. Now I have two very good solutions to my problem, my new problem is to choose one :-). I think that I didn't clearly stated my environment from the beginning. More thanks for your time.